# Android 6 notification drawer width landscape mode

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow, notification-bar

I recently upgraded my Motorola Droid 4 from CM11 (Android 4.4) to CM13 (Android 6). Now when I pull down the notification drawer in landscape mode, the notifications don't fill the whole screen. There is a margin to the left and the right side of the notifications.
This margin seems to be a fixed ammount of pixels, as on higher DPI devices it is much smaller. Since my Droid 4 only has a rather low resolution, the margins take about one third of the screen width.
Is there any way to get it back to the way it was in CM11?

I have root and don't mind installing a new notification bar app (as long as it's not terribly slow, I am on a rather old device) or even recompiling parts of Android/CM.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that's part of the new M layout. I'm not sure if you can change it, even in CM.

Comment: Also not using a different notification drawer app?

Comment: Oh, you might be able to. I'm not sure as I haven't researched that.

Comment: Maybe moving the 4.4 System UI to 6.0 (someone else can help?)